# Cannot install hyperledger composer-cli on ubuntu because of g++

Tags: hyperledger-composer

On ubuntu 18.04 I get an eror when I try to install the hyperledger local development environment as supposed in 
https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/develop/installing/development-tools.html.
It tells me that it doesn't know the g++ command.

My configuration listing:

```
npm: v6.9.0
docker: 18.x
docker-compose: 1.24
node: 10.15.3 (also tried with v11.10.0 and 8.9)
npm: 6.4.1
git: 2.17.1
Python 2.7.14
```

Following the error log after running "npm install -g composer-cli":

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.3.0: core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/bin/composer -> /home/myuser   /.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js

> dtrace-provider@0.8.7 install /home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider
> node-gyp rebuild || node suppress-error.js

make: Verzeichnis „/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build“ wird betreten
TOUCH Release/obj.target/DTraceProviderStub.stamp
make: Verzeichnis „/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build“ wird verlassen

> node-report@2.2.1 install /home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Verzeichnis „/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report/build“ wird betreten
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/api/src/node_report.o
make: g++: Command not found
api.target.mk:107: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/api/src/node_report.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/api/src/node_report.o] Error 127
make: Verzeichnis „/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report/build“ wird verlassen
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-47-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/bin/node" "/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report
gyp ERR! node -v v8.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-report@2.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-report@2.2.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/myuser/.npm/_logs/2019-04-05T08_35_08_242Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your node & npm version. Below is the requirement:

Node: 8.9 or higher (note version 9 is not supported)
npm: v5.x

I have both and able to install it successfully on Ubuntu 18.

Comment: Thank you, Gaurang for your quick response but I also considered the prerequisites as mentioned in:
https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/develop/installing/installing-prereqs.html
I added the configuration listing above.

Comment: remove this folder "/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules"  from your PC and try to install it again with above mentioned node and npm version.

Comment: Oh yes, it seems to be a configuration problem with node. After removing the folder and trying again I got a permission error. I am not able to continue with this at the moment but I will let you know later next week.